# D3: How to conditionally bind SVG objects to data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have here an array of objects that I'm visualising using D3. I bind each object to a group element and append to that an SVG graphic that depends on some object property, roughly like this:

```
var iconGroups = zoomArea.selectAll("g.icons")
        .data(resources)
        .enter()
        .append("g")

var icons = iconGroups.append(function(d){
         if(d.type == "Apple"){
             return appleIcon;
         }else if(d.type == "Orange"){
             return orangeIcon;
         })
```

etc. Now I'd like to extend some of those icons with an additional line. I could add a line element for each data point and set them visible only where applicable, but since I want to add them only for say one out of a hundred data points, that seems inefficient. Is there a way to bind SVG lines to only those objects where `d.type == "Apple"`?

Comment: Do you want to append icon only if the d.type == "Apple" ?

Comment: @murli2308 the icons are always appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create separate selections for icons and lines, this way:

```
var iconGroups = zoomArea.selectAll('g.icons')
  .data(resources);
iconGroups
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('icons', true);
iconGroups.exit().remove();

var icons = iconGroups.selectAll('.icon').data(function(d) {return [d];});
icons
  .enter()
  .append(function(d) {
    if(d.type === 'Apple'){
      return appleIcon;
    }else if(d.type === 'Orange'){
      return orangeIcon;
    }        
  }).classed('icon', true);
icons.exit().remove();

var lines = iconGroups.selectAll('.line').data(function(d) {
  return d.type === 'Apple' ? [d] : [];
});
lines
  .enter()
  .append('line')
  .classed('line', true);
lines.exit().remove();
```

.exit().remove() is added just because I add it always to be sure that updates work better. :)

Maybe the code is longer than .filter() but I use the following structure all the time and it's easier to scale it.

edit: apropos comment - If you need to pass indexes, you should pass them in binded data:

```
var iconGroups = zoomArea.selectAll('g.icons')
  .data(resources.map(function(resource, index) {
    return Object.create(resource, {index: index})
  }));
```

(Object.create() was used just to not mutate the data, you can use _.clone, Object.assign() or just mutate it if it does not bother you)

then you can access it like:

```
lines.attr("x1", function(d){ console.log(d.index);})
```

Comment: Much like using `filter`, this method does not seem to retain the data indices. `lines.attr("x1", function(d, i){ console.log(i);})` reveals that `i` is always 0.

Comment: I've edited my answer so you can use the index now. You can even change the map so it returns only the values which you need, for example `return {type: resource.type, shouldAppendLine: resource.type === 'Apple'}`

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you earlier. It does work! What still bothers me a little is that `lines` still contains as many elements as `data`. I'm thinking using a `filter` in conjunction with the added `index` property could fix that..

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to the icons to be selected (e.g. appleIcon), and use that class in a selector to add the lines.

Comment: Nice and simple approach, however I need to bind the lines to the data since their attributes depend on data properties.

Comment: In that case, why don't you filter the data instead of passing to selection.filter? As also written in the doc what you have quoted already: *To bind elements to only a subset of the data, call the built-in array filter on the argument to data.*

Comment: Well because _something_ is bound to each data point, I can't just remove entries.

Answer (score 1):

Use d3 filter.

```
selection.filter(selector)
```

Filters the selection, returning a new selection that contains only the elements for which the specified selector is true.

Reference: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter

Demo: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8dc93bce7e7200ab487d

Comment: Unfortunately, filter does not retain the original selection index, which I need later to set the line attributes. From the documentation: _Like the built-in function, D3's filter does not preserve the index of the original selection in the returned selection; it returns a copy with elements removed. If you want to preserve the index, use select instead._ I've tried `iconGroups.select(function(d){return d.TypeName == "Apple";})`, but that keeps returning all icon groups, while `iconGroups.filter(function(d){return d.TypeName == "Apple";})` returns the correct subset (but without correct index)